# Tag Values in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to use bash shell to replace the existing tag value with the preferred tag value for azure resources.  A single resource can have multiple tag values.

Comment: Where's the resource name coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my test, we can use the following script to update tags value

```
Connect-AzAccount

$t = import-csv E:\test.csv 

Foreach($t1 in $t){
  # get the resources which has the tag
  $resources=Get-AzResource -Tag @{$t1.TagName=$t1.TagValue}

  #update the tag
  foreach($resource in $resources){

    $tags =(Get-AzResource -ResourceId $resource.Id).Tags
    $tags[$t1.TagName]=$t1.PreferredTagValue

    $result =Set-AzResource -Tag $tags -ResourceId $resource.Id -Force
    $result.Tags

  }
}
```

My CSV file

[image]

Comment: It works has expected..but anyways to get from excel instead of CSV..

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [Set-AzResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/set-azresource?view=azps-2.8.0) to set tags on an Azure resource.

```
$r = Get-AzResource -ResourceName examplevnet -ResourceGroupName examplegroup
$r.Tags.Add("Status", "Approved")
Set-AzResource -Tag $r.Tags -ResourceId $r.ResourceId -Force
```

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-using-tags).